# .htaccess RewriteRule issue I cannot resolve

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Current URL:

```
/shop/?display=category&id=cloths
```

Rewritten to:

```
/shop/cloths
```

With the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/\.]+)$ /shop/index.php?display=category&id=$1 [L]
```

The trouble is I need to be able to add further $_GET variables to the url for example:

```
/shop/cloths?page=2
```

I cannot figure out the rule that’s needed for this. I don’t want to limit the name of the extra variables either, so I could have:

```
/shop/cloths?page=
/shop/cloths?filter=
/shop/cloths?page=&filter=
```

Comment: Do you need to pass the GET variables on to `/shop/cloths` or just match them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/\.]+)$ /shop/index.php?display=category&id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa